# What is the next step of creating a Django website after "startproject mySite"?

Tags: google, dns, 301-redirect, search

I would like to start web designing using django!
but Whenever i type "django-admin.py startproject mySite" in cmd this code popup through notepad, Then what should I do?

```
#!c:\users\crepin\envs\myproject\scripts\python.exe
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should start with the official Django tutorial, it explains everything: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/ .

Comment: Single line answers and link only answers are generally not good enough here.   While the link you provide does look helpful, it would be better to give more direction.  It sounds like the person that asked may have already been using a tutorial and is stuck in a certain place.